# How to add an object into another class? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, class, object

**I have ana assignment(which means that I have to be quite strict with what methods I use).**

So I have this class File which **simulates** a file. All it does is - it conatains either nil or a single string, or a single symbol, or a single number or a single boolean (true/false). So I have a method that `initializes` a file, I also have a method `data_type` which determines the type (`#class`) of the contents of the file, a getter/setter, etc..

I also have this `class Dictionary` which may contain other directories and files. I should have the following methods inside of it:

- `add_file(name, file)` - which adds a file named `name`. `file` should be an object of `class File` but we have no need to check whether the input object really belongs to this class.
- `add_directory(name, directory)` - which adds a directory with the name `name`. `directory` is an object of `class Directory`. It may be missed, in which case an empty directory is created.

etc.. etc..

I have done all of my `class File` methods but I have a problem making the two methods I mention in `class Directory`. They have a lot of similarities so a comment on the `add_file(name, file)` one only should be enough.

All I could think of is `name = File.new` but not only does it not work but it also leaves out the `file` thing which I have totally no idea what is.

```
def add_file(name, file)
  name = File.new
  @name = name
end
```

This is, of course, highly incorrect but was all I could think of.

All help is appreciated. Thank you! And I'm sorry for asking so silly questions.

**And remember, this is a simulation only! Those files aren't actual files. `file` is just a random name which fits. I highly doubt I should `require` anything!**

EDIT: A friend of mine mentioned that the file probably already exists. I might just have to match it with this `name`. However.. I'm still highly confused.

EDIT2: Something in the lines of `@files[name] = file` with `@files` being a hash?

Comment: Do the files already exist? Or you're trying to create them blank and then add them?

Comment: Adding from scratch.

Comment: **It should look something like this def add_file(name, file) with name being the name of the file and file being an object of class File.**  Your File class doesn't define an instance variable named @name?

Comment: @7stud look at my updated question. Should be a easier to understand. And no, it doesn't.

Comment: This question doesn't seem very clear to me. I read through it twice and I still don't understand exactly what you're asking. Is this just an "implement these methods for me" kind of question? Or do you actually have something specific you're trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the class `File` to a different name as there is already a `File` class.

Any way I'm guessing that that it works like this:

Ok, so I re-read your op and realised that Dictionary was a typo and thus redid the code so it now resembles:

```
class Directory
  attr_accessor :name,:store

  def initialize name
    self.name = name
    self.store = {}
  end

  def add_file(file)
    self.store[file.name] = file
  end

  def add_directory(directory)
    self.store[directory.name] = directory
  end

  def [](name)
    self.store[name]
  end

end

class File
  attr_accessor :name, :content, :data_type

  def initialize name,content = nil,data_type = nil
    self.content = content
    self.name = name
    self.data_type = data_type || content.class
  end

end
```

then you can do

```
file1 = File.new('hw.rb','puts "hello world!"', 'ruby file')
file2 = File.new('gbw.rb','puts "good bye world!"', 'ruby file')
root = Directory.new('root')
rb = Directory.new('rb')
rb.add_file(file1)
root.add_file(file2)
root.add_directory(rb)

puts root['rb']['hw.rb'].content
```

and if you used a splat operator argument in the `add_file` and `add_directory` methods you could then itterate through the argument and add each file so you could use it like

```
file1 = File.new('hw.rb','puts "hello world!"', 'ruby file')
file2 = File.new('gbw.rb','puts "good bye world!"', 'ruby file')
root = Directory.new('root')
root.add_file(file1,file2)
```

research 'ruby splat operator arguments' for information on what I mean